# Cannot create a Publication named 'android' because this container does not support creating elements by name alone

Tags: android, gradle, artifactory

I'm using Gradle to publish a number of variants on Artifactory, and following an example I've found online, I've used this code:

```
 publishing {
     publications {
         android.buildTypes.all { variant ->
             "${variant.name}Aar"(MavenPublication) {
                 artifactId = "artifactory_artifactId-${variant.name}"
                 groupId = "artifactory_groupId"
                 version = "v1.0.0"
                 // Going off of default Gradle naming configurations
                 artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-${variant.name}.aar")

                 artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-${variant.name}.aar") {
                     classifier variant.name
                     extension "aar"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

These are my plugins and dependencies:

```
 dependencies {
     classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
     classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
     classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release'
 }
```

When I synchronise my files on Android Studio, in the console the following error is printed:

"Cannot create a Publication named 'android' because this container does not support creating elements by name alone. Please specify which subtype of Publication to create. Known subtypes are: MavenPublication"

I don't understand which import should I make to solve my problem. What should I import of "android"?

I should be able to use the "variant" object in order to publish dynamically the `.aar` files together without specifying them all separately. If there's an alternative, I'll be happy to use it.